# when I hash my password on the client side , I am not getting the hashed string instead getting the password itself

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, netbeans, hash

I am trying to hash my password on the client-side before sending it to my server(Tomcat server), when I click on submit the form is getting submitted before updating the value of the password to hashcode
how can I make sure That my form gets submitted after the script is executed?
or is there a better way to go by this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="encrypt(event);" action="login" >
        <input type="text" name="user_id">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="pass">
        <button id="but1" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
function encrypt(event){
//  event.preventDefault();//prevents from form getting auto submitted              
document.querySelector("body").style.color="red";             
sha512(document.getElementById("pass").value).then((x)=> 
{                
document.getElementById("pass").value=x;                   
document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = x;
});
}


            function sha512(str) {
            return crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-512", new TextEncoder("utf- 
8").encode(str)).then(buf => {
            return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buf), x=> 
(('00'+x.toString(16)).slice(-2))).join('');
            });
            }
            sha512("my string for hashing").then(x => console.log(x)); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit your form after the process

```
 <form id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="encrypt(event);" action="login" >
        <input type="text" name="user_id">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="pass">
        <button id="but1" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>


function encrypt(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevents from form getting auto submitted
  document.querySelector("body").style.color = "red";
  sha512(document.getElementById("pass").value).then((x) => {
    document.getElementById("pass").value = x;
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("form1").submit(); // submitting the form
  });
}
```